# Q: retention.bytes setting in kafka 0.10.2 is not clear

Tags: apache-kafka

I was thinking about using this setting in server.properties, and also in per topic configuration. I don't know whether it's per partition, per broker, per topic setting? In 0.8.2 documentation it says: "**Note that this is the limit per-partition so multiply by the number of partitions to get the total data retained for the topic**."
But in 0.10.2 it doesn't say that: "**The maximum size of the log before deleting it**"
We are running 0.10.2.1
TIA.

Comment: Both statements are not in contradiction with each other since log is at per-partition level.

Comment: So it's still per partition level?

Comment: yes, it controls the total bytes for all the segments under one single log.